# How does SQL check if a record exists?

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, primary-key

I have a SQLite database and am using the `INSERT OR IGNORE` query. I have a table with an autoincrementing int as the primary key and also another unique column. My question is, how does SQLite check if the record already exists, so that it knows whether or not to ignore it? Does it scan the primary keys first and then any other unique columns? If so, it it possible for it to compare the unique column before the primary key for some queries? Also if a column is unique, is it already indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIQUE constraints are implemented using indexes, so UNIQUE columns are already indexed.

When evaluating INSERT OR IGNORE, if *any* UNIQUE constraint in the table would be violated by the INSERT statement, the OR IGNORE is used instead.  The order of evaluation is not important from a functional point of view and should have a tiny performance impact.  Presumably the order of evaluation is handled by the query optimizer but, if not, again the performance hit should be small.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there would be a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how deep you want to go, I might recommend [downloading the SQLite3 source code](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and starting to search through it for terms like "unique" and "constraint" - some answers to your question can be provided by reading through the source in just a few minutes.

The code appears to be **unusually well documented**. If you're going to use SQLite heavily it might not be a bad idea to at least read through the comments provided. I'll bet more insight than you might expect will come from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Often searching through code, I get confused due the lack of any decent documentation. Will take a look through this one though for other interesting tips.